# Page naming covention for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page which is opening as

http://localhost/mywp/?page_id=9596

Now i want to do custom theming for this page. i made page-9596.php file which is not working?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom Page Template and assign that Page template from worpdress backend. You can create different design for each page Template.

For more details please read following link.
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/?ench=b&utm_expid=3606929-78.ZpdulKKETQ6NTaUGxBaTgQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F

Comment: This is a problem that cannot be solved without your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a page type post in your WP, and want to give it a custom template, then you have to consider this priority list:

1. Page Template — If the page has a custom template assigned,
   WordPress looks for that file and, if found, uses it.
2. page-{slug}.php — If no custom template has been assigned, WordPress
   looks for and uses a specialized template that contains the page’s
   slug.
3. page-{id}.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s
   slug is not found, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized
   template named with the page’s ID.
4. page.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s ID is
   not found, WordPress looks for and uses the theme’s default page
   template.
5. index.php — If no specific page templates are assigned or found,
   WordPress defaults back to using the theme’s index file to render
   pages.

(Lower number means higher priority, found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

So, you may have a page-{slug}.php or a special Page Template assigned (they are of higher priority than page-{id}.php).

The other thing is: if you create a Page Template (highest priority), the template's PHP file **must** start with this:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Template Name: Yourtemplatename
 *
 */
```

and you have to assign this new "Yourtemplatename" to the page on the WP admin ("Yourtemplatename" must also be unique in the WP installation, as it is a system wide identifier).

Other problems cannot be answered, unless exact code is provided.

Comment: I agree with the naming convention and all that, but if it is just for one page, then you don't need to create a page template. Just simple make a new php file called page-{slug}.php and chuck all the code you need for that page there. You don't need the Template name stuff

Comment: Correct - just wanted to give a hint about what might have gone wrong. Usually I try not to use special templates for one page - rather have a general template, that can be modified in the "content" - and give some tools (e.g. shortcode libraries) to the user to do it without the need to know HTML / CSS / JS. This way they can have layouts they want - without me meddling all the time with their customisation needs.